# if(isset) condition isn't stopping php as expected

Tags: php, forms

I'm using the following to place signatures on a pdf. The img, img2, & img3 fields on my form contain the signatures as strings. It works perfectly, as long as all 3 fields contain data/signatures. If any are left blank, the script stops at

```
file_put_contents($image, base64_decode($arr[1]));
```

When I don't sign one or more signatures, Firebug confirms that no postdata is being sent for that field. So I must be doing something wrong in the php.

Shouldn't the code below stop all the image processing if the referenced field was empty?

Is there a different way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!

```
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');
$pdf = new FPDI('P', 'mm', 'Letter');
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($ffn);
for($i = 1 ; $i <= $pagecount ; $i++){
    $tpl  = $pdf->importPage($i);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tpl, 0, 0);
    if ($i==7) {
        if(isset($_POST['img'])){
            $hash = uniqid();
            $arr = explode(',',$_POST['img']);
            $image = dirname(__FILE__).'/results/sig'.$hash.'.png';
            file_put_contents($image, base64_decode($arr[1]));
            $pdf->Image($image,38,193,-200);
        };
        if(isset($_POST['img2'])){
            $hash2 = uniqid();
            $arr2 = explode(',',$_POST['img2']);
            $image2 = dirname(__FILE__).'/results/sig'.$hash2.'.png';
            file_put_contents($image2, base64_decode($arr2[1]));
            $pdf->Image($image2,38,217,-200);
        };
        if(isset($_POST['img3'])){
            $hash3 = uniqid();
            $arr3 = explode(',',$_POST['img3']);
            $image3 = dirname(__FILE__).'/results/sig'.$hash3.'.png';
            file_put_contents($image3, base64_decode($arr3[1]));
            $pdf->Image($image3,38,241,-200);
        };
    };
    if ($i==8) {
        $locmap = $_POST['_fid_209'];
        $pdf->Image('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:blue%7Clabel:I%7C'.$locmap.'&zoom=14&size=800x800&sensor=false',63,90,90,0,'PNG');
    };
}
$pdf->Output($ffn, 'F');
```

Comment: you seem to have answered your question in your question :) **Shouldn't the code below stop all the image processing if the referenced field was `empty`?** use the `empty()` function

Comment: How so? To be clear, the script is moving through the code (and breaking) even when img fields are empty. I need to prevent those 5 lines below each if(isset) from happening if the field is empty.

Comment: don't use `isset`, use `if(!empty())` its a text field, it will ALWAYS be set on a post

Comment: Thanks Randy! Works. Now I know. Do you want to add this as an answer? Or should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['img']) && !empty($_POST['img'])) {
```

....

Comment: Thanks mjayt. I went with if(!empty($_POST['img'])){ by itself as suggested by Randy above. Any reason to include isset as well? I'll mark this one as answered.